# Hosting for adult website and easy registration?

Tags: hosting, shared-hosting

I need a shared host, Linux, for a PHP application: My website contains adult content, payment is monthly.

1. First, I don't speak English, I used godaddy but my website cant access many times ( even now is not).
2. I checked Bluehost, Mediatemple (they don't allow porn websites)
   Hostgator request "a scanned copy of
   a Photo ID such as a passport", it is too complicated, Dreamhost requests 60$ on first server setup.
3. Can you suggest an easy registration and realible hosting, register with credits card like as Goddady, register very fast but poor server.

Answer (score 3):

Adult content is legally problematic. I am not saying impossible, but:

> Hostgator request "a scanned copy of a
>   Photo ID such as a passport", it's too
>   complicated

Every sensible host will require a Photo ID. You're talking of adult content, not pictures of furniture.

You should go to specialist adult hosters. There are some.

> 1. First, I don't speak English

Try to improve your English or get someone who handles this. No English means you are limited to whatever miserable part of the world you live (including mine - I am from a non-english speaking country), while pretty much everyone can *also* deal in English.

Then, seriously, understand that in many countries (all?) adult content is problematic. Some paperwork IS required.